# What is the difference between .empty().append() and .html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Using jQuery, what's the performance difference between using:

```
$('#somDiv').empty().append('text To Insert')
```

and

```
$('#somDiv').html('text To Insert')
```

?

Comment: You continue to change your question based on answers.  What's your *real* end question?

As you've written it, no functional difference.

If you cared about speed, you should have said something about speed in your question.

Comment: -1 for changing your root question and invalidating a number of answers.

Comment: -1 To backup Stefan, and because I don't care if I lose a point.

Comment: One might assume that `html()` is backed by `innerHTML` and `append()` is backed by `appendChild()`, of which case, there are differences, namely in what the browser needs to do and what information can be lost during the serialisation/deserialisation process.

Answer (score 50):

`$('#somDiv').html(value)` is equivalent to `$('#somDiv').empty().append(value)`.

Source: [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/22449eb/src/manipulation.js#L425).

Comment: Is .append faster than .html?

Comment: @AppleTrue: slow down on the updates man! ;) I've updated my answer to your latest question....

Comment: `.empty().append(...)` will be marginally faster since `.html(...)` is essentially a wrapper for the same thing. Don't use `.empty().append(...)` for the sake of speed, since you wouldn't notice a difference in even several thousand calls, and it would be confusing to someone reading your code.

Comment: The jQuery documentation would lead you to believe that if you are trying to add an existing jQuery, element, array, or Text that you cannot use `.html` since it says it only accepts an `htmlString` or `function`...however it does call `.empty().append()` internally and passing it an existing jQuery does work.

Answer (score 6):

.html will overwrite the contents of the DIV.

.append will add to the contents of the DIV.

Comment: Does append use DOM? Whereas innerHTML does not?

Comment: Please note that I have included the empty() function to that append is overwriting like .html.  Is .append faster than .html?

Comment: @J-P: in all fairness from the timestamps it seems the OP heavily edited the question from typo-ridden to sensible.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for. I wish more SO answers were as concise and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

difference between `append()` and `html()` in jQuery

`.append()` and `.html()` are the most useful methods in jQuery. But these are far different from one another, `.append()` add some value to the existing one. Where `.html()` do the same but it removes the old value first.

Here is an example:

```
<ul id="test">
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Now I will use `.append()` to add one `<li>`, For that I will write:

```
<script type="text/javascript>"
jQuery("#test").append("<li>test1</li>");
</script>
```

The output of this jQuery will be:

```
<ul id="test">
<li>test</li>
<li>test1</li>
</ul>
```

Now if I use `.html()` to add one `<li>`, For that I will write:

```
<script type="text/javascript>"
jQuery("#test").html("<li>test1</li>");
</script>
```

The output of this Script will be:

```
<ul id="test">
<li>test1</li>
</ul>
```

Here in this example `.append()` add one extra `<li>`, whether `.html()` removes the old one with new one. This is the main difference between `.append()` and `.html()` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:

```
$('#somDiv').append('blabla')
```

works like this:

```
<div id='somDiv'>some text</div>
```

becomes:

```
<div id='somDiv'>some textblabla</div>
```

And innerHTML replaces the contents, so it becomes this:

```
<div id='somDiv'>blabla</div>
```

Comment: I've updated my original post to include the empty() function so that they act the same

Comment: They are exactly the same in terms of result but innerHTML would probably be faster on big files as it just uses the native function, which is only 1 call.

Comment: Is .append faster than .html?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
$("#somDiv").html("<span>Hello world</span>");
```

Comment: I've updated my original post. Now what's the difference? (Thanks)

Comment: Functionally, now there is no difference.