# Is there a performance difference between 'append' vs 'html'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between .empty().append() and .html() in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903063/what-is-the-difference-between-empty-append-and-html-in-jquery)

1. Using jQuery, is there a difference in performance between:

   ```
   $('#somDiv').empty().append('text To Insert')
   ```

   and

   ```
   $('#somDiv').html('text To Insert')
   ```

   ?
2. Also, does one method parse the input as a DOM object before the insert vs simply just inserting? (Meaning, does method simply inject the HTML vs internally creating a DOM object)?

   ```
   $('#somDiv').empty().append('text to Insert')
   ```

   vs

   ```
   $('#somDiv').html('text to Insert')
   ```

   ?

Comment: Per a suggestion on another thread of mine, I have completely re-worded my question and have started over with a new post --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903063/jquery-empty-append-vs-html-whats-the-difference

Comment: You already have an answer to this question though!

Comment: @Shog9, no - my answer is related to "what's the difference" functionality in the other post. This new question is, how does performance compare and does one method vs another use DOM.

Comment: but **somebody already answered that**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903063/jquery-empty-append-vs-html-whats-the-difference/1903090#1903090

Comment: Again, the first question has already been answered in one of the answers to the question you link to. The second part might have merit, but... I'm not quite sure what you're asking! I've edited the question based on my limited understanding of what you're asking; feel free to clarify further...

Comment: @Shog9, you have misunderstood my 2nd question. So I have rewritten my second part. See original post for the update

Comment: why don't you *measure* their performance yourself?

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Given that your first question has been answered, I've removed the second from that. I suggest you ask a new question, and this time **be very, very specific** about what you're actually looking for.