# default select on ajax conditional dropdown select

Tags: php, ajax

Need help for setting up a default select option form my conditional dropdown select.

**Here is my first dropdown select**

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
    @foreach($categories as $cats)
    <option value="{{$cats->id}}">{{$cats->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**My dependent dropdown is like this**

```
<select name="product" id="product">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $('#category').on('change',function(e){
        console.log(e);

            var cat_id = e.target.value;
            $.get('/products?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data){
            $('#product').empty();

            $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
            $('#product').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

For a simple dropdown select, like the categories one, simply used the  and it worked fine, but how can I have this default select for the products drowdown select?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can append something like this

```
 $('#product').empty();
 $('#product').append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select Product</option>');
            });
$.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
            $('#product').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
            });
```

i have seen you have used `$('#product').empty();` and hence your included `<option value=""></option>` is getting removed altogether which you put in your html.

You can use **.html()** instead of **.append()** so you do not need to `$('#product').empty();` as **.html()** will overwrite your dom.

And then you can only need to put this in your html

```
<select name="product" id="product">

</select>
```

And your javascript will be something like this

```
<script>
    $('#category').on('change',function(e){
        console.log(e);

            var cat_id = e.target.value;
            var response = '';
            $.get('/products?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data){
            response = '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Product</option>';

                  $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
                      response .= '<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>';
                  });

            $('#product').html(response);
            });
    });
</script>
```

you can find difference between **.html()** and **.append()** here [What is the difference between .empty().append() and .html()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903063/what-is-the-difference-between-empty-append-and-html)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Mit.agile. It is working now! Thank you for suggesting the .html() also. I will try it later on.